# Расположить элементы в круге

Tags: html, css

Элементы расположены по кругу, с наездом друг на друга.
Как сделать так что бы каждый элементы был выше предыдущего но ниже следующего.
Сейчас получается что первый элемент либо выше двух соседних либо ниже.

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/6kNTL/2/)

Красный квадрат должен быть выше черного, но ниже зеленого

Comment: При помощи только z-index-ов тут не выехать. Получается, если смотреть на индексы классов, замкнутый круг: a>b>c>d>a.

Comment: Как этого не сделать я тоже знаю :)
Как бы вот сделать два красных квадрата, но чтоб показывалась только половина и один из них был бы сверху а другой снизу.

Comment: К последнему квадрату (черному) добавьте псевдо-элемент `:after`, так чтобы размер соответствовал 1/4 обычного квадрата, а фон был красным: http://jsfiddle.net/6kNTL/4/

Comment: Уже похоже на то что надо, а как быть с кругом например?
http://jsfiddle.net/6kNTL/5/

Comment: Оформите в виде ответа, мне подходит)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/6kNTL/7/